# Trying to rearrange data such that at cells are individually labelled with the heading, rather than just all being under the same single heading

Tags: r, dataframe

Here is the data I'm working with:

[image]

I want to replace all of the "NA_____"s with the most recent non "NA" value from the "FullName" column.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 2):

You can try `na.locf` from `zoo`:

```
library(zoo)
df$FullName <- na.locf(with(df, ifelse(FullName == "NA_____", NA, FullName)))
```